# objective c adjusting word cloud for different screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a word cloud and now I have a problem that when I change the size of the view the words in word cloud are not adjusting itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct way the constraints of all elements inside parent view after try to do it:

```
[view setNeedsLayout];
[view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: I am using a uiview(cloudview) and uilabels and putting uilabels as the subview for the uiview(cloudview).

Comment: The  problem is not in the view, the problem is when I change the uiview size of the word cloud the fonts size gets bigger or smaller..

Comment: Try to modified constraint (width|height) instead of frame directly and put constraints to uilables relatives to cloud view. If not you have to change manually all frames of uilabels inside cloud view...

Comment: In this case you need set **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** to YES.

Comment: I am using two integers(minFontsize and maxFontsize with some constant value) for the maximum and minimum font size for the words and adding these two values to the wordcount of each word. now for screen size 320X500, the word cloud is showing perfectly but when I change the screen size to something else the word are not resizing properly... please help..

Comment: I think the two integers minFontsize and maxFontsize values should be changed according to the screen size but I dont know how to do it..

Comment: The problem is that attributes minFontSize|maxFontSize don't change frame to uilabels. That attributes are only to adapt the 'text' according to a determinate frame. You have to change frame manually.

I recommended you use auto layout and layout constraint. See more information about it here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html)

Comment: Thank You very much for that link and and for your answers.. I will surely try that...

Comment: i can not use auto layout because the position and size of uilabels are not fixed.

Comment: You can change position and size using auto layout through to constraint. But try in your current code (without auto layout) to change the frame of labels manually and it would be work (you give value to min and max fontSize attributes).

Comment: i tried you solutions but it didn't work properly, so i tried to initialize maxFontsize=height/8 and minFontsize=maxFontsize*0.16. or maxFontsize=width/8 and minFontsize=maxFontsize*0.16 and it worked for me.... and still thank you very much for your time and for solutions...